# Laravel DB sub query and select in sub query

Tags: laravel

```
SELECT mc.pr_category_id, mc.parents, mc.level, mc.lft, mc.rgt, mcdscr.cat_name FROM table_cat as mc
RIGHT JOIN
    ( SELECT c.*, dscr.cat_name FROM table_cat AS c 
        JOIN table_cat_description AS dscr ON c.pr_category_id = dscr.pr_category_id AND c.pr_category_id = $pr_category_id 
    ) AS test ON (mc.rgt < test.rgt) AND mc.lft > test.lft
JOIN table_cat_description AS mcdscr ON mc.pr_category_id = mcdscr.pr_category_id 
ORDER BY mcdscr.cat_name ASC
```

I'm using leftJoin but not work. Could you help sub query?

Comment: Can you explain little more

Comment: what ur trying to achive

Answer (score 0):

No tested.. But Idea should be there somewhere.

```
$sql1 = DB::table(DB::raw('SELECT c.*, dscr.cat_name FROM table_cat AS c JOIN table_cat_description AS dscr ON c.pr_category_id = dscr.pr_category_id AND c.pr_category_id = $pr_category_id 
    '));
$sql2 = DB::table(DB::raw('SELECT mc.pr_category_id, mc.parents, mc.level, mc.lft, mc.rgt, mcdscr.cat_name'));

$query = DB::table(DB::raw("($sql) AS mc"))->leftJoin(DB::raw('($sql2) as test'), function($join)
        {
        $join->on('mc.rgt', '<', 'test.rgt');
        $join->on('mc.lft', '>', 'test.lft');
        })
    ->join('table_cat_description AS mcdscr', 'mc.pr_category_id', '=', 'mcdscr.pr_category_id')
    ->orderBy('mcdscr.cat_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return $data = DB::table("table_cat ")
     ->select("table_cat_description .*")
     ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT c.*, dscr.cat_name FROM table_cat AS c 
                 JOIN table_cat_description AS dscr ON c.pr_category_id = dscr.pr_category_id 
                 AND c.pr_category_id = 20 AND dscr.lang = 'vi'
             ) as test"),function($join){
             $join->on('test.pr_category_id', '=', 'pp_product_category.pr_category_id');
             $join->orOn('test.parents', '=', 'pp_product_category.pr_category_id');
     })
     ->join('table_cat_description ', 'table_cat .pr_category_id', '=', 'pp_product_category_desc.pr_category_id')
     ->whereRaw("table_cat_description.lang = 'en'")
     ->orderBy('table_cat .level', 'asc')
     ->get();
```

I am using query and working. Thank you so much